# video in html5 is not working in IE

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am using the html5 video tag to play the video and html5.js to show the video in popup in wordpress. video is working in firefox and chrome but not in IE.  In IE9and IE10 .it is showing only image in IE.Please let me know how can I fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To enable the new HTML5 tags in Internet Explorer, you need to insert a simple javascript code on your page so that IE can understand the new tags. The code is responsible for the following:

```
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

:)